# Variable de archivoA.cpp no se actualiza con valor de variable de archivoB.cpp

Tags: c++, variables, hilos, qt, herencia

Tengo un programa en Qt con C++ con las siguientes clase:

main.cpp: solo ejecuto la interfaz.

mainwindow.cpp: ejecuto las acciones que debe realizar mi programa según ciertos datos de una imagen

myvideocapture.cpp (que es un qthread por lo del procesamiento que puede tardar), tengo mi código para captura y procesamiento de datos. Aquí tengo dos funciones una "run()" que captura la imagen y otro "procesamiento" que procesa la imagen.

Todo está definido. El programa casi funciona bien.
En myvideocapture tengo una variable entera llamada "Xcapture" y ésta contiene un valor después del procesamiento. En la clase mainwindow, tengo una variable llamada "XmainW" en la que quiero almacenar el valor de "Xcapture". O sea pasar el dato de mainvideocapture->mainwindow.
Cuando compilo el programa, éste casi funciona bien, la variable Xcapture contiene el valor que quiero después de procesar, pero este valor no se pasa a XmainW. Cómo puedo pasar ese valor de myvideocapture a mainwindow?

Nota: si algo tiene que ver, uso camara camara genie nano y API Sapera LT para la captura de la imagen, esta es la forma más conveniente de trabajar con esta camara

**myvideocapture.h**

```
#ifndef MYVIDEOCAPTURE_H
#define MYVIDEOCAPTURE_H
#include <QImage>
#include <QThread>
#include <SapClassBasic.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <mainwindow.h>
#include "iostream"

class MyVideoCapture : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyVideoCapture(QObject *parent=nullptr);

    int radius=0;
    int centrocamaraX1=0;
    int centrocamaray1=0;
    int Xcapture=0; //cuando pongo aquí borro la del .cpp 

protected:
    void run() override;
    char     ccfcamara1[82]="C:\\Program Files\\Teledyne DALSA\\Sapera\\CamFiles\\User\\T_Nano-M1450_DA_1.ccf";
    char     nombrecamara1[13] = "Nano-M1450_1";
    int      numerodecamara1 =0; //empieza desde 1 index 0 es del sistema
    void procesamiento(SapBuffer *pSapBuf); //para el procesamiento
    static void XferCallback(SapXferCallbackInfo *pInfo);  //para la captura


private:
   QPixmap mPixmap; 
   cv::Mat mFrame;
   cv::Mat exportImg; 
    int centrox=0; // otros datos que se obtienen en el procesamiento
    int centroy=0; // otros datos que se obtienen en el procesamiento
};

#endif // MYVIDEOCAPTURE_H
```

**myvideocapture.cpp**

```
//int Xcapture=0;
void MyVideoCapture::run()
{
// captura de imagen - codigo de camara
AcqDeviceToBuf = SapAcqDeviceToBuf(&AcqDevice, &Buffers, XferCallback, &View); // esta sentencia llama a la funcion estatica
// mas codigo de la camara
}

void MyVideoCapture::XferCallback(SapXferCallbackInfo *pInfo)
{
MyVideoCapture pasarimagen;
SapView *pView =(SapView *) pInfo->GetContext();
SapBuffer* Buffer_View = (pView->GetBuffer());
pasarimagen.procesamiento(Buffer_View); // llamo a procesamiento
qDebug()<<Xcapture; // hasta aqui tambien muestra el dato deseado
}



void MyVideoCapture::procesamiento ()
{
// procesamiento de imagen
// aqui se asigna un valor a Xcapture ej.
Xcapture=245;
// imprimo el valor para verificar que si contiene el dato
qDebug()<<Xcapture; //se confirma que el dato es el esperado
}
```

**mainwindows.cpp**

```
mvideoCapture = new MyVideoCapture(this);
int XMainW;
XMainW=mvideoCapture->Xcapture;
// no recupera el valor de la variable, solo muestra el valor cero de inicialización
// proceso a hacer con el dato de XMainW
```

He intentado accediendo directo al dato de Xcapture, por ejemplo

```
if(mvideoCapture->Xcapture==valor)
{
  // codigo requerido
}
```

sin embargo el valor de Xcapture me sale cero, es decir, solo me pasa el dato inicializado y no el dato que se asigna después del procesamiento. Qué error estoy cometiendo o cómo puedo realizar lo que quiero? Se agradece mucho la ayuda

Comment: Podrías pasar el código del **myvideocapture.h**?

Comment: ya lo he puesto @Mateo

Comment: Creo que los problemas se deben por un lado a que no defines correctamente las funciones. Debes anteponer el nombre de la clase al nombre de la función. Así: `void MyVideoCapture::run(){}`

Comment: Por otro lado tienes una variable `Xcapture`  que solo está en la unidad de traducción de `myvideocapture.cpp`. Simplemente quitala, si la clase ya tiene una variable llamada así. Solo está molestando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como vemos, `Xcapture` es una variable miembro de `MyVideoCapture`:

```
class MyVideoCapture : public QThread
{
public:
    int Xcapture=0; // Variable miembro de MyVideoCapture
```

Esto quiere decir que cada instancia de `MyVideoCapture` tendrá su propia variable `Xcapture`, es decir, dos instancias de `MyVideoCapture` podrán tener valores diferentes para esta variable.

Si vemos la función de captura:

```
void MyVideoCapture::XferCallback(SapXferCallbackInfo *pInfo)
{
    MyVideoCapture pasarimagen;
    SapView *pView =(SapView *) pInfo->GetContext();
    SapBuffer* Buffer_View = (pView->GetBuffer());
    pasarimagen.procesamiento(Buffer_View); // llamo a procesamiento
    qDebug()<<Xcapture; // hasta aqui tambien muestra el dato deseado
}
```

Ya encontramos el primer error:

```
qDebug()<<Xcapture;
```

Dado que esta función es estática, `Xcapture` **no existe para esta función**. `XferCallback` es una función estática, es decir, no está ligada a una instancia de `MyVideoCapture` y, en consecuencia, no tiene acceso a esta variable miembro. Sí podría funcionar, en cambio, el siguiente código:

```
qDebug() << pasarimagen.Xcapture;
```

Efectivamente, esta función estática crea una instancia de `MyVideoCapture`. Esta instancia sí que tiene su propia versión de `Xcapture`.

Pero claro, aquí tenemos un pequeño inconveniente, y es que la instancia que se crea dentro de la función `XferCallback` se destruye cuando la ejecución abandona dicha función y con ello pierdes el valor de `Xcapture`.

Si necesitas que el valor de `Xcapture` perdure, tienes que almacenarlo en un sitio más persistente. Esto podrías hacerlo, por ejemplo, marcando la variable `Xcapture` como `static`. Al hacer este cambio todas las instancias de `MyVideoCapture` compartirán la misma variable e incluso el valor podrá ser recuperado sin necesidad de una instancia:

```
std::cout << MyVideoCapture::Xcapture;
```

Esta solución entiendo que únicamente funcionará en el caso de que exista una única cámara. Si no es el caso, tendrás que repensar el diseño de la aplicación

En cualquier caso ya te aviso que a la función `XferCallback` le da absolutamente igual que la clase `MyVideoCapture` herede de `QThread`. Esa función se va a ejecutar en el hilo que invoque la función. No se cómo está estructurada la aplicación, pero creo que la arquitectura de la misma es un poco confusa.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he intentado eso en mi programa y no funciona. Ahora, aquí ha habido un error mío en la presentación del código, (ya lo actualicé). Pasa que la función run() tiene una sentencia que llama a una clase protegida estática (es importante que sea estática porque así trabaja la API de la cámara) y dentro de esta función estática se llama a la clase procesamiento, por ello he creado un objeto "pasarimagen" dentro de la funcion XferCallback (creo que aquí es donde falla). La culpa ha sido mia por no exponer bien la situación, espero que ahora pueda ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: ok, poniendo xCapture como static sí que me ha funcionado. Con eso ya puedo cerrar la pregunta (me gustaría saber cómo). Por otro lado, por qué funcionaría con solo una cámara? te refieres a una cámara en esa misma clase o a una cámara en todo el proyecto? porque manejo 3 cámaras, cada una en su propio Qthread, y cuando tenga el dato de todas, puedo continuar con mi proceso en mainwindow. Ahora no lo he probado con las 3 porque aún no me llegan las otras dos, pero si existe un problema me gustaría estar preparado

Comment: @ADR simplemente marca mi respuesta como solución (el tick verde que debería aparecer debajo de los puntos de la respuesta)

Comment: @ADR esta solución solo te permite trabajar con una cámara por vez porque solo tienes una variable `xCapture` en la aplicación. Si intentases usar dos cámaras, el valor de `xCapture` se sobreescribiría constantemente

Comment: ok, gracias por todo